# Updating inner doc from mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my sample doc.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f20148a85e39af87510305"),
    "group_name" : "sai",
    "privileges" : [
        "Notification",
        "News Letter"
    ],
    "users" : [
        {
            "full_name" : "sumit",
            "user_name" : "sumitdesh",
            "password" : "magicmoments",
            "status" : "Active"
        },
        {
            "full_name" : "ad",
            "user_name" : "asd",
            "password" : "asdf",
            "status" : "Active"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to replace inner doc from users array with a new doc.

This is my java code:

```
BasicDBObject g1=new BasicDBObject();
g1.put("full_name", "ram");
g1.put("user_name", "ram123");
g1.put("password", "pass$123");
g1.put("status", "Inactive");
BasicDBObject doc=new BasicDBObject();
doc.put("users",g1);
BasicDBObject q=new BasicDBObject("users.user_name","asd");
con.update(q,doc);
```

Any help is appreciated

Expected output is as follows
I want to replace inner doc with these values

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51f20148a85e39af87510305"),
        "group_name" : "sai",
        "privileges" : [
            "Notification",
            "News Letter"
        ],
        "users" : [
            {
                "full_name" : "sumit",
                "user_name" : "sumitdesh",
                "password" : "magicmoments",
                "status" : "Active"
            },
            {
                "full_name" : "ram",
                "user_name" : "ram123",
                "password" : "pass$123",
                "status" : "Inactive"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you want to do is achievable, but I'm having trouble understanding what it is. Could you edit your question to show an example of what you expect the output BSON object to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must combine [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) and [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#op._S_) operators, then you can update an specific item of array.

```
BasicDBObject g1 = new BasicDBObject();
g1.put("users.$.full_name", "ram");
g1.put("users.$.user_name", "ram123");
g1.put("users.$.password", "pass$123");
g1.put("users.$.status", "Inactive");

BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
doc.put("$set", g1);

BasicDBObject q = new BasicDBObject("users.user_name","asd");
con.update(q,doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will create a new document consisting only of the new user. To add a new element to an array in an existing document, use the $push operator

```
BasicDBObject where = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId("51f20148a85e39af87510305");
BasicDBObject doc = //... your new user object
BasicDBObject push = new BasicDBObject("$push", doc);
con.update(where, push);
```

To modify a field of an existing document, you can use the set-operator combined with the $-placeholder. This changes the user_name from "foo" to "bar"

```
BasicDBObject where =  new BasicDBObject("users.user_name", "foo");
BasicDBObject value =  new BasicDBObject("users.$.user_name", "bar");
BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", value);
con.update(where, set);
```

But the least headache-inducing way is to just keep the whole DBObject around when you retrieve an object from the database, mirror all modifications in the DBObject, and then call

```
con.save(dbObject);
```

An ORM wrapper library can do this for you. But while it is the easiest way, it isn't the most efficient way, because the whole document will be sent to the database. This is a problem which can be easily filed under "premature optimization" when writes are infrequent and the documents are small, but when you save often and have huge documents, it can become an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually fairly simple, if you follow the documentation.

The first difficulty is finding the document to update. You're looking for the user whose `user_name` field is 'asd', which is done, rather neatly, through the following query:

```
{'users.user_name': 'asd'}
```

The field name needs to be escaped in the mongo shell (it's a compound name) but you need not worry about that in Java.

Now that you've found your user, you need to change it. MongoDB magically stores the matched array index as `$`, which allows you to write the update criteria as:

```
{
    $set: {
        'users.$': {
            full_name: 'ram',
            user_name: 'ram123',
            password: 'pass$123',
            status: 'inactive'
        }
    }
}
```

You obviously know your way around the Java connector, I'll leave the transformation of my JSON object to instances of `BasicDBObject` to you.